# XMPP BOSH Response issue

Tags: javascript, xmpp, strophe, punjab

I am new with XMPP web client and bosh. I am using stropher js for chat demo.

On my server punjab bosh installed successfully. I am sending below request for connection establish in post on bosh server url.

**Request :**

```
<body rid='2122769834' xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind' to='MY server Domain URL' xml:lang='en' wait='60' hold='1' content='text/xml; charset=utf-8' ver='1.6' xmpp:version='1.0' xmlns:xmpp='urn:xmpp:xbosh'/>
```

**Response :**

```
<body xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind' inactivity='60' secure='true' authid='f3fccd4d' content='text/xml; charset=utf-8' window='3' polling='15' sid='a72390785c3cce0c819e6f0943143fae54625258' requests='2' wait='60'/>
```

And giving me continuous status as a **connecting**  and when response get from above request its would send automatically new below request data.

**Request**

```
<body rid='2122769835' xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind' sid='a72390785c3cce0c819e6f0943143fae54625258'/>
```

**Response :**

```
<body xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind'/>
```

and continuous send above request and getting above response. I tried with different different demo. But every where i am getting same type of data.

I am not getting why my login credentials authentication not performing.

Please help me...!!

Thanks in advance..!!

Answer (score 0):

You're not done. Once you get the SID back from the server, you need to authenticate, restart, bind the resource, restart, etc. See http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0206.html.